# Is any infinitesimal extension of an affine scheme affine?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory

If $X$ is an affine scheme with coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$, $Y$ any scheme with

$$0 \rightarrow \mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_Y \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X \rightarrow 0$$

exact such that $\mathcal{F}^2=0 \subset \mathcal{O}_Y$. Is $Y$ necessarily affine too?

In more details, if $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{O}_Y$ is a sheaf of ideals that squares to zero, such that the schemes $X$ with structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$ is isomorphic to the scheme $Y'=(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y/\mathcal{F})$, is then $Y$ with its own structure sheaf affine?

Comment: So you are asking: If $\operatorname{Spec} A \to Y$ is a closed immersion w.r.t to an nilpotent ideal sheaf (of nilpotence index 2), is $Y$ affine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes:

If $Y'=(Y,\mathcal O_Y/\mathcal F)$ is affine for some nilpotent $\mathcal F$, then $Y_{red}=(Y,\mathcal O_Y/\operatorname{nil}(\mathcal O_Y))$ is also affine, because this is a closed subscheme of the affine scheme $Y'$.

It is well known that a scheme is affine if and only if its reduced scheme structure is affine. In the noetherian case, this is very easy, but it is also true in the general case, [see here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95/is-there-an-example-of-a-scheme-x-whose-reduction-x-red-is-affine-but-x-is-not-a).

Thus we conclude that $Y$ is affine.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a reference for the very easy noetherian case, which does not go through Serre's criterion?